# Kendo grid dynamic model field binding issue with kendo version 2013.3.1119

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, model-binding

I have use Kendo version 2012.03.1114 and below mention code to add value to model and work fine but when I update the kendo varsion to 2013.3.1119 it will give a error

> (TypeError: $(...).data(...).kendoGrid.editable is undefined)

any workaround please?

```
var model = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid.editable.options.model;
model.set('Name', getNames());
```

---

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ABC.Domain.Entities.user>() 
.Name("Grid") 
.Columns(columns => { 
columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); }).Width(80); 
columns.Bound(u => u.Name).Title("Name").Width(150); 
columns.Bound(u => u.Status).Title("Status").Width(70); 
columns.Bound(u => u.Address).Title("Address").Width(100); }) 
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("userEdit")) .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound").Edit("onEdit")) 
.Pageable(paging => paging.PageSizes(new int[] { 5, 10, 20, 50 })
.Refresh(true)) 
.Sortable() .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()) 
.Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true)) 
.Scrollable() 
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource .Ajax() .Model(model => { model.Id(p => p.userKey); }) .PageSize(5) .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler")) 
.Read(read => read.Action("user_Read", "User")) 
.Update(update => update.Action("User_Update", "User")) 
.Create(create => create.Action("User_Create", "User")) ) )
```

Comment: Can you plaase upload whole grid creation code and format code in your post to be readable?

Comment: var model = $('#grid').data().kendoGrid.editable.options.model; model.set('Name',getNames());  @j4ro

Comment: @j4ro problem with new version previously its work fine now its says  (TypeError: $(...).data(...).kendoGrid.editable is undefined) thanks.